# xcode External Accessories Programming

Tags: xcode, usb, hardware, external

Im creating an app that can receive data over a USB port. Do you have any tutorial on how to this? I guess this has something to do with `<ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h>`

I really appreciate if you guys will provide a sample project. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of device do you plug to your iPhone?
Did you joined the [MFI Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)?

You need to, if you need one of [these capabilities](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-1).

Did you think about Bluetooth for you project?
(Bluetooth profiles that don't need MFI enrollment -> [link](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647))

**Remember:** MFI program is a big choice.
Do you plan to sell a product? Do you plan to sell a big number of parts (2000+, 40$ each)?
If one of these answer is "no", forget about MFI program.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided [a sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/eademo/Introduction/Intro.html).